# How to submit x-data via hx-vals with htmx

Tags: alpine.js, htmx

Anyone know how to do this? I have parent div with `x-data="checkboxHandler"`

The `x-data` itself is working but I cannot get it to submit with the htmx request.

The JS error is that none type does not have length.

I know that with Alpine store you can do something like I tried below but it is not working with data.

Any help would be amazing.

```html
<input type="button"
           value="Submit"
           hx-get='/example
           hx-target="#hx_modal_container"
           hx-vals='js:{"total": Alpine.$data('checkboxHandler').checkedValues.length}' # This is the line that is not working
/>
```

The x-data

```js
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
            Alpine.data('checkboxHandler', () => ({
                checkedValues:[],
                selectAll: false,
                total(){this.checkedValues.length},
                addAll() {
                    this.selectAll=true
                    const allPageValues=JSON.parse(document.getElementById('all_rows_ids').textContent)
                    this.checkedValues=[]
                    this.checkedValues.push(...allPageValues.map(value => value.toString()))
                    this.checkedValues.push('all')
                 },
                 removeAll() {
                    this.selectAll=false
                    const allPageValues=JSON.parse(document.getElementById('all_rows_ids').textContent)
                    this.checkedValues = this.checkedValues.filter(value => !allPageValues.map(value=>value.toString()).includes(value))
                    const index= this.checkedValues.indexOf('all')
                    this.checkedValues.splice(index, 1);
                 }
     
                
            }))
           
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```html
<input type="button"
           value="Submit"
           hx-get="/example"
           hx-target="#hx_modal_container"
           x-bind:hx-vals="JSON.stringify({"total": Alpine.$data('checkboxHandler').checkedValues.length})"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

*x-data* object can't be accessed by external JS and *Alpine.data()* is a *'write-only'* method, moreover *$store* is a magic property that can be accessed only from *AlpineJS* code.

You must use the *AlpineJS store* to share data with JS:

```HTML
<div>
    <input type="button"
           value="Submit"
           hx-get="/example"
           hx-target="#hx_modal_container"
           hx-vals="js:{total: Alpine.store('checkedValues').length}"
    />

</div>

<script>

    document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {

        Alpine.store("checkedValues", []);

        Alpine.data("checkboxHandler", () => ({

            selectAll: false,
            total(){this.$store.checkedValues.length},

            addAll() {
                this.selectAll=true
                const allPageValues=JSON.parse(document.getElementById('all_rows_ids').textContent)
                this.$store.checkedValues=[]
                this.$store.checkedValues.push(...allPageValues.map(value => value.toString()))
                this.$store.checkedValues.push('all')
            },

            removeAll() {
                this.selectAll=false
                const allPageValues=JSON.parse(document.getElementById('all_rows_ids').textContent)
                this.$store.checkedValues = this.$store.checkedValues.filter(value => !allPageValues.map(value=>value.toString()).includes(value))
                const index= this.$store.checkedValues.indexOf('all')
                this.$store.checkedValues.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }))

    })

</script>
```

The *checkedValues* variable is now placed into the store.
Inside the Alpine object it is accessed via the magic property *$store*, while in the JS (htmx here) is accessed using the *Alpine.store()* method